# PHP syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php

Im geting an error message of Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in E:\Websites\xxx.php line 29 
Line 29 is

```
$_REQUEST["id"]);
```

Here are theadditional codes
Thanks in advance

```
if
(
$mydb->execute("Update Diamond Set name = <name>, weight = <weight>, colour = <color>, cut = <cut>, where ID = <id>", 
$_REQUEST["name"], 
$_REQUEST["weight"],
$_REQUEST["color"],
$_REQUEST["cut"],
$_REQUEST["id"]);
$onloaddo = "alert('Saved existing diamond ".$_REQUEST["id"]."');";
$diamondid = "";
}
else
($_REQUEST["submitter"] == "Search")
{
if($_REQUEST["searchdiamondid"] != null && $_REQUEST["searchdiamondid"] != "")
{
$queryres = $mydb->query("Select id from diamond where id=%
$_REQUEST["searchdiamondid"]);
if ($queryres->countReturnedRows()==0)
$onloaddo="alert('diamond ID ".$_REQUEST['searchdiamondid']." not found!');";
else
{
$resultrow = $queryres->fetchRow();
$diamondid = $resultrow['diamondid'];
$name = $resultrow['name'];
$weight = $resultrow['weight'];
$colour = $resultrow['color'];
$cut = $resultrow['cut'];
$id = $resultrow['id'];
$formmode = 3;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you, my poor indent ?

Comment: Your code sample is littered with syntax errors, so fixing one will just produce another.

Comment: Even code highlighter on SO shows what is wrong here...

Answer (score 3):

There are many syntax errors with your code:

```
1. if has missing closing round bracket
2. SQL query is incorrect
3. else is evaluating a condition like if or else-if
4. $queryres = $mydb->query() has missing double quote
5. And probably few more
```

I strongly suggest you to:

1. indent your code properly to make it more readable
2. If possible use an IDE to code

Answer (score 1):

Remove comma in `<cut>,`

change

```
$mydb->execute("Update Diamond Set name = <name>, weight = <weight>, colour = <color>, cut = <cut>, where ID = <id>",
```

to

```
$mydb->execute("Update Diamond Set name = <name>, weight = <weight>, colour = <color>, cut = <cut> where ID = <id>",
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing parenthesis of your first if statement

Answer (score 0):

$_REQUEST(["id"]);

You were missing the (

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$queryres = $mydb->query("Select id from diamond where id=%$_REQUEST["searchdiamondid"]);
```

to

```
 $queryres = $mydb->query("Select id from diamond where id=". $_REQUEST["searchdiamondid"]);
```

If your $mydb->query function doesn't handle it:

I recommend, google for MySQL security stuff like 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: No, don't do this, it introduces a security vulnerability.  Don't ever append user-supplied strings to SQL like this.

Comment: @Jim the sql-string looks same. it depends on what the query-function handles in the background.